# Can a single IIS7 Website Bindings be set in a web.config file?

Tags: iis-7, configuration, website, bindings

when I setup my websites, I need to manually set the bindings for the site, in the UI of the website, in IIS7.

Can these bindings be defined in the web.config instead? Is there a section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in the web.config, but you can set it in a number of ways other than the IIS 7 managment gui. See the [binding reference](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/sites/site/bindings/binding) on the iis website

Comment: /me cries like an emo kid :( :(